# Chart - Recurrent Action

Tags: arrows, charts

How may I draw the lines that connect the arrows? This is the code I managed to write, it might be messy and untidy as I'm new to Latex

```
\begin{center}
    $ \downarrow \linebreak
\fbox{\parbox{4 cm}{In x(n); \hspace{0.1 cm} A/D\linebreak Out x(n-1);%
\hspace{0.1 cm} D/A\linebreak x(n-1) = x(n);\hspace{00.1 cm} Shift}} \linebreak
\downarrow$
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the wonderful interaction between the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) packages:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{enhanced,listing only,hbox,remember as=mycode,colframe=green!60!black,colback=white}
In x(n);        A/D
Out x(n-1);     D/A
x(n-1) = x(n);  Shift
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=latex]
\draw[->]
  (mycode.south) -- ([yshift=-30pt]mycode.south);
\draw
  ([yshift=-30pt]mycode.south) -- 
  ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-30pt]mycode.south east) |-
  ([yshift=30pt]mycode.north);
\draw[->]
  ([yshift=30pt]mycode.north) -- (mycode.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```